# I am getting an issue while scheduling a run in AWS Device Farm from CLI

Tags: aws

I am using this command for executing from CLI -

```
aws devicefarm schedule-run --project-arn "project-arm value" --app-arn "app-arm value" --device-pool-arn "device-pool-arm value" --name "Automated_script" --test '{"type":"APPIUM_JAVA_TESTNG","testPackageArn":"testPackageArn value"}`
```

But getting this error

```
"An error occurred (ArgumentException) when calling the ScheduleRun operation: Missing or unprocessed resources."
```

Can anyone help me in solving this? Thanks in advance